# How to find the owner of an Instagram app - got a AppId and AppSecret/ClientToken

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

My code base contains references to an Instagram server-to-server app, complete with AppId and AppSecret.
The code request access tokens and do API calls successfully - all good.

However, I need to login to the apps administrative pages (on developers.facebook.com) to make certain changes, but I can't remember the Facebook/Instagram user account that is the owner of the app. It might have been a throw-away account created just for the purpose of creating the app, or might have been one of the earlier owners of the code base I inherited.

Given that I can prove app ownership via AppId/AppSecret, are there any way to recover the App-owners id or e-mail or anything that will somehow help me login to the apps administrative pages?

Note: I have tried [https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/[my-app-id]](https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/%5Bmy-app-id%5D) but the response I get is:

> "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '[my-app-id]' does not exist,
> cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this
> operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at
> [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api%22)

Comment: What token did you use for this request? If you use the combination of `app_id|app_secret`, which always constitutes a valid app access token, this should work. `/app-id/roles` should get you all the accounts with a role in the app then.

Comment: Well, it changed the response at least. The response I get now is:
"error": {
        "message": "Error validating application. Cannot get application info due to a system error.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 190,
        "fbtrace_id": "..."
    }
Token is added as Bearer, if this is relevant...

Comment: The usual way to pass it is as a GET or POST parameter named `access_token`. I doubt it is relevant though – since the error message you’re getting has changed, passing it as bearer must have had effect already. But double-checking, just to make sure, probably doesn’t hurt either.

Comment: Tried the access_token parameter, but got the same result as with the bearer token. But thank you for your suggestions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The AppId/AppSecret the code base used was defined under Products -> Instagram Basic Display of an existing app I have access to. I got confused because the apps AppId/AppSecret is different from that in the code base. I did not expect an app to sub-sets of AppID/AppSecrets, but what do you know.